# Compacting records into single rows using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am processing a dataset which is coming in from a CSV file and there are a lot of duplicate column values, although rows do have one column which is different.

Here is an example:

```
Pandas(Index=457, id='ABC1', type='factory', name='ABC Factory', country='GB',  machine='X6754')
Pandas(Index=458, id='ABC1', type='factory', name='ABC Factory', country='GB', machine='ZHG89')
```

Is it possible to compact this down into a single record in the dataframe? I want to convert this to json so ideally it would look like:

```
Pandas(Index=458, id='ABC1', type='factory', name='ABC Factory', country='GB', machines=['X6754', 'ZHG89'])
```

This post is only asking a single question which has been answered already, so in defence of keeping it open I would say if you are unable to answer a question, that is not grounds to close or delete it.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you're showing me (looks like the initializer call or repr for some custom object), and I don't know what rules you actually want to implement.

Comment: If you are uncertain look at the answer below.

Comment: The output I showed was just print lines for an iteration over a dataframe, I do not have any custom objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you can use `groupby`:

```
common_cols = ['id', 'type', 'name', 'country']
out = df.groupby(common_cols, as_index=False).agg({'machine': list})
print(out)

# Output
     id     type         name country         machine
0  ABC1  factory  ABC Factory      GB  [X6754, ZHG89]
```

Setup:

```
>>> df
       id     type         name country machine
457  ABC1  factory  ABC Factory      GB   X6754
458  ABC1  factory  ABC Factory      GB   ZHG89
```